# JPA + Hibernate + autocommit

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Does anybody know why I get this warning when I turn off the auto-commit in JPA configuration file?

Using this setting :

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
```

generates this warning :

```
2009-08-04 09:54:10,621 [main] WARN org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration - hibernate.connection.autocommit = false break the EJB3 specification
```

How would this break EJB3 specification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From section 13.3.4 of the EJB 3.0 specification:

> The enterprise bean’s business
>   methods, message listener methods,
>   business method interceptor methods,life cycle call back interceptor
>   methods, or timeout callback method
>   must not use any resource-manager
>   speciﬁc transaction management methods
>   that would interfere with the
>   container’s demarcation of 
>   transaction boundaries. For example,
>   **the enterprise bean methods must not use the following methods**  of the
>   java.sql.Connection interface:commit,
>   **setAutoCommit**, and rollback; or the following methods of the
>   javax.jms.Session interface:commit and
>   rollback.

Comment: I don't have any methods like that, the message occurs only if I set hibernate.connection.autocommit=true in JPA configuration.

Comment: Hibernate probably calls that method itself. I'm guessing you don't need to specifiy autocommit=false

Comment: Not sure about that. Here is what the code looks like:

//some spec compliance checking
857  //TODO centralize that?
858  if ( ! "true".equalsIgnoreCase( cfg.getProperty( Environment.AUTOCOMMIT ) ) ) {
859  log.warn( Environment.AUTOCOMMIT + " = false break the EJB3 specification" );
860  } 

Also something from docs:
hibernate.connection.autocommit : Enables autocommit for JDBC pooled connections (it is not recommended).e.g. true | false 

I presume it's just a warning as Miguel noted(not sure if it is still used) and since you must start a transaction anyway, this doesn't makes sense now.

Comment: Ok, didn't come out well, code in comments doesn't work.

Conclusion : not need it, you will have to start a transaction even for inserting a single record(you get an exception if you don't). Still I cannot find a document saying that this is obsolete(or some better explanation).